# How to create a function containing custom var

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I have written the following function to sync some input fields:

```
$(".dp1").on('change', function(e){
    var dateValue = $($(this)[0]).val();
    $.each($('.dp1'), function(index, item){
        $(item).val(dateValue);
    });
});

$(".dp2").on('change', function(e){
    var dateValue = $($(this)[0]).val();
    $.each($('.dp2'), function(index, item){
        $(item).val(dateValue);
    });
});

$(".rooms").on('keyup', function(e){
    var dateValue = $($(this)[0]).val();
    $.each($('.rooms'), function(index, item){
        $(item).val(dateValue);
    });
});

$(".persons").on('keyup', function(e){
    var dateValue = $($(this)[0]).val();
    $.each($('.persons'), function(index, item){
        $(item).val(dateValue);
    });
});
```

As the function is the exact same one every time, I guess there is a better way to combine it into one. I am thinking of something like

```
my_custom_function(my_custom_value){
   var dateValue = $($(this)[0]).val();
   $.each($('my_custom_value'), function(index, item){
       $(item).val(dateValue);
   });
}
my_custom_function('.dp1, .dp2, .rooms, .persons');
```

I know there is a way but I do not know how to achieve this. I am very thankful if someone is able to help me out!

Comment: are you looking for some things like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/49fn1jhk/

Comment: and also try this one http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/49fn1jhk/1/

Comment: FYI, `$($(this)[0]).val();` is the same as `$(this).val();`, and you can probably just use `this.value`.

Comment: As always, identify what is fixed and what is variable (the selector and the event name). Then create a function that contains the fixed part as the body (with the variable parts substituted with, wait for it, *variables*)  and accepts the variable parts as arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a common function and call the function with approprite parameters.

```js
function my_custom_function(selector, event) {
    $(selector).on(event, function (e) {
        var dateValue = this.value;
        $.each($(selector), function (index, item) {
            $(item).val(dateValue);
            console.log(item);
        });
    });
}

my_custom_function(".dp1", "change")

my_custom_function(".dp2", "change")

my_custom_function(".rooms", "keyup")

my_custom_function(".persons", "keyup")
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="dp1"></input>
<input type="text" class="dp1"></input>
<br/>
<input type="text" class="dp2"></input>
<input type="text" class="dp2"></input>
<br/>
<input type="text" class="rooms"></input>
<input type="text" class="rooms"></input>
<br/>
<input type="text" class="persons"></input>
<input type="text" class="persons"></input>
```

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/49fn1jhk/1/